# При нажатии на кнопку задать новый цвет и убрать цвет с предыдущей

Tags: java, android, android-on-click

У меня есть 6 кнопок. При нажатии на любую из них я хочу задать новый цвет или drawble и вернуть предыдущей кнопке её начальный цвет, чтобы всегда выделялась одна кнопка:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_t1:
        Call_Adapter(0);
        break;
    case R.id.button_t2:
        Call_Adapter(1);
        break;
    case R.id.button_t3:
        Call_Adapter(2);
        break;
    case R.id.button_t4:
        Call_Adapter(3);
        break;
    case R.id.button_t5:
        Call_Adapter(4);
        break;
    case R.id.button_t6:
        Call_Adapter(5);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы по моему пытаетесь переизобрести [RadioButton и RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html). Эти два контрола из коробки умеют делать всё что вы описали. [Вот хорошая статья](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/radiobutton.php) на русском о том как их использовать.

Answer (score 2):

1. Создайте массив/список всех кнопок.
2. При нажатии на к-л кнопку пробегайтесь по массиву/списку и проставьте им дефолтные цвета.
3. После этого нажатой кнопке присвойте нужный цвет, демонстрирующий нажатие.

---

Ещё можно через `Selector`. По нажатию на кнопку у всех кнопок снять `selected`, нажатой проставить. И в `Selector`-e задать цвета.